# How do I run Excel Macros on an iPad?

Tags: excel, vba, ipad

So I have two macros in an Excel file. One is for deleting unused sheets and the other is for converting sheets to PDF. Now I want these macros to run on an iPad Excel app. Is it possible? If it's not what's the alternative. I read somewhere that you can convert VBA code to OfficeJS and it will work on iPad? Is that true?

Comment: Here you have a list of features in Excel for iPad. Macros are not supported. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-for-iphone-features-faac09c9-51af-4b3c-8c20-16c10145eff3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Is there any alternative like converting the macros to another language?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/

Comment: I think you may need to rewrite the macros to use on the web.